# Darken background on cell (not row)

Tags: html, css

I have a table, stripped. Some cells are editable. For each row, a different sets of cells are editable. Since this is confusing, I want to provide a visual feedback to the user. All editable cells have an `.editable` class on the `td`. I have tried two things:

- add a border to editable cells: unsatisfactory, because the border is not shown all around the cells: surrounding cells, which share a border, are not editable, and then only part of the border is shown. Very ugly.
- change the background of editable cells: this is working, but completely breaks the stripped style of the table. Also ugly.

This is my try with borders:

[image]

This is my try with background:

[image]

What I would like to do is to slightly darken the background of the editable cells, so that the stripped nature of the table is conserved, but at the same time a visual feedback is provided for editable cells.

How can I apply a "filter" (is that what this is?) do slightly darken cells with an `editable` class?

Comment: You can just give all cells with a `.editable` class a slightly darker `background-color`. Alternatively, you can give them all a `background-color` of `#000` (black), and an `opacity` of `0.6`. Then all cells with the `.editable` class can have an `opacity` of `0.8`.

Comment: @Druzion: much too complex. I already get a stripped table for free, and don't want to change its styles (I do not even want to know how it gets styled). I just want to slightly modify the styles with a filter for cells with a specific class, with simple CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `RGBA`color like:

```
.editable {
  background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

The example above is black with 0.2 opacity: **[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/alvaromenendez/u6uLvpz5/)**

Answer (score 0):

Utilize the class as a CSS selector like so (you can obviously set whatever background color you want, this is just to illustrate the point):

```
td.editable:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #F4F4F4;
}
td.editable:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #EEE;
}
```

Comment: I have already tried that, and it completely changes the stripped nature of the table. I want to darken, not to force a color.